# Iframe parent url

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How do I get an Iframe's parent window url using jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

Just include the url when opening the iframe.

```
<iframe 
src="http://foo.bar/iframe.html?iframeparentwindowurl=http://cheese.tv/parrot.html">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

For script running in the iframe, use `parent.location.href`, although an iframe served from a different domain to its parent page will not be able to access this.

If you are on separate domains, there are a few alternative techniques that should work for you. In particular, using the window.name to pass data, or stacking iframes within iframes. Both, and more, are listed in [this slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/SlexAxton/breaking-the-cross-domain-barrier). Window.name is mentioned on slide 31. Especially check out slide 34 and on for the iframe stacking technique, which will enable bidirectional communication between differing origin iframes.