# how to get the querystring from a parent page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am using an iframe ipage in my parentpage. I would like to get the querystring in javascript of the parentpage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string
...for the page you're in. hmm!

Comment: How you are redirecting to next page?

Comment: can you include the parent url in the iframe src? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743751/iframe-parent-url

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript). Any of the solutions there can have `window.location.search` replaced with `window.parent.location.search` to work on the parent frame instead.

Comment: Future readers: don't forget to look at the answers' dates! Only one answer uses remotely recent (ES6) functionality

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest to you to use my favourite function:

```
 function getQueryString() {
                var queryStringKeyValue = window.parent.location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
                var qsJsonObject = {};
                if (queryStringKeyValue != '') {
                    for (i = 0; i < queryStringKeyValue.length; i++) {
                        qsJsonObject[queryStringKeyValue[i].split('=')[0]] = queryStringKeyValue[i].split('=')[1];
                    }
                }
                return qsJsonObject;
            }
```

Just call it from the child window like this and act with the query string as an object.

For example if you have the query string `?name=stack` and you want to get it, try:

```
getQueryString().name
```

This will return `stack`.

Comment: May I ask why that last line is `return ((qsJsonObject != null) ? (qsJsonObject) : (null));` instead of just `return qsJsonObject;`? With the code as is, qsJsonObject will never be null, since when it's declared it's assigned to an empty object.

Comment: oh yes sorry :D it may be a leak from an old code ;) thanks i edited it

Answer (score 1):

nice answer from @Marawan. - if it helps anyone...
I extended this to choose the target as a parameter (self / parent)

```
function getQueryString(target) {
    if ( target == 'parent' ) {
        var queryStringKeyValue = window.parent.location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
    }
    else {
        var queryStringKeyValue = window.location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
    }

    var qsJsonObject = {};
    if (queryStringKeyValue != '') {
        for (i = 0; i < queryStringKeyValue.length; i++) {
            qsJsonObject[queryStringKeyValue[i].split('=')[0]] = queryStringKeyValue[i].split('=')[1];
        }
    }
    return qsJsonObject;
}
```

eg.

```
getQueryString('parent').id;    // get iframe parent url ?id=foo
getQueryString().id;    // get this url ?id=foo
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 implementation:

```
export const getQueryParameters = () => {
    const queryStringKeyValue = window.parent.location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
    return queryStringKeyValue.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const [key,value] = curr.split('=')
        return {
            ...acc,
            [key]: value
        }
    }, {})
}
```

Usage:

```
getQueryParameters().name
```